# list minimum rust version required for rust project

Tags: rust, version

**tl;dr** how do I list the minimum rust version required for my project and dependencies?

In my rust project, each entry in `Cargo.toml` section `[dependencies]` may have some minimum rust version required. I want to list those version requirements per dependency. This is in order to understand the minimum rust version for the my rust project.

Of course, for each dependency, I could find it's `Cargo.toml` and note any `rust-version` entry. And then repeat that for each of it's dependencies. But that is a time-consuming manual process. I was hoping for a `cargo` command or a tool that would effectively do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install and use [cargo-msrv](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-msrv) for that ("MSRV" means "minimum-supported Rust version"); it has multiple commands that can help.

For example `cargo msrv list` will list the advertised Rust versions of your crate, its dependencies, and any transitive dependencies. Below is for an empty package with a `chrono` dependency:

```
> cargo msrv list
Fetching index
┌────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ MSRV   ┆ Dependency                                                                │
╞════════╪═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│        ┆ mycrate, chrono, winapi, wasm-bindgen, time, num-traits, num-integer,     │
│        ┆ js-sys, iana-time-zone, winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu,                     │
│        ┆ winapi-i686-pc-windows-gnu, wasm-bindgen-macro, cfg-if, wasi, libc,       │
│        ┆ autocfg, iana-time-zone-haiku, core-foundation-sys,                       │
│        ┆ android_system_properties, wasm-bindgen-macro-support,                    │
│        ┆ wasm-bindgen-shared, wasm-bindgen-backend, codespan-reporting, cc, log,   │
│        ┆ bumpalo, unicode-width, termcolor, winapi-util                            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.0.0  ┆ scratch                                                                   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.31.0 ┆ quote, syn, proc-macro2, unicode-ident                                    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.34.0 ┆ link-cplusplus                                                            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.48.0 ┆ cxx-build, cxx, cxxbridge-macro, cxxbridge-flags                          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.56.0 ┆ once_cell                                                                 │
└────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

You may notice though, that many crates do not have a `rust-version` documented in their Cargo.toml. So you should be careful that, just because highest minimum reported is `1.56.0`, you don't mistake that for a guarantee that 1.57.0 (for example) will work.

For that, the basic `cargo msrv` will install and check your crate with various versions of Rust to see whether it works or not:

```
> cargo msrv
Fetching index
Determining the Minimum Supported Rust Version (MSRV) for toolchain x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Using check command cargo check
Check for toolchain '1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' succeeded
Check for toolchain '1.58.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' succeeded
Check for toolchain '1.57.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' succeeded
Check for toolchain '1.56.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' succeeded
   Finished The MSRV is: 1.56.1
```